Why would solid rubber tubes be no good to some?
I've had solid rubber bike inner tubes for years. No problems. No flats in years. I had way too many of these because of the increase in trash on the roads these days.

In short: High rolling resistance, high mass, bad comfort.
Even virtually puncture proof pneumatic tyres with very thick rubber layers like the Schwalbe Marathon Plus perform better in those aspects.
Solid rubber tyres are pretty much only used for rental city bikes or rental wheelchairs which have a very high priority on reliability and low maintenance. Nobody who rents them expects them to be fast (i.e. roll well) or be light.
